# c function not printing when called and jump to the next function

Tags: c, function, printf, function-parameter

I am trying to make  a game  called Tic-Tac-Toe-Tomek(variation of Tic-Tac-Toe).For now, i am making the win checking system.
I us the inputs 'X','O','T' and '.' for space
I use printf to  see how the functions  work. later i will remove them.
the output will be

if x win the last output  will be 'X'

if o win the last output  will be 'o'

if there is draw the last output will be '='

if the game in progress the last output will be '?'

---

My problem is that function dia2_check(game[][4]) does not work 
because it does not printing the check .When the input is

```
...X
..X.
.X..
X...
```

the output should be

```
some reports 
then 
dia2 0 check 3 x=1 o=0
dia2 1 check 2 x=2 o=0
dia2 2 check 1 x=3 o=0
dia2 3 check 0 x=4 o=0
then x
```

but what i get is

```
some reports then
dia 0 check 0 x=1 o=0
.
.
dia 3 check 3 x=4 o=0
( which  all is right) then
draw 0 col 0 D 0
draw 0 col 1 D 0
.
.
.
draw 3 col 3 D 4
```

the program jumped checking dia2 and start checking draw.
her is the code

```
        #include<stdio.h>

    /*how the program will worke 
    A)set functions 
        1-row check
        2-column check
        3 diagonal check
        4 the other diagonal check
        5 draw and game in progress check
        6 call functions (which will control and  check all the possibilities  using the  
          other functions )
     B)main 
        will take the input pass it to the functions 
    */


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int row_check(char game[4][4])
    {/*row check*/
        int xwin;
        int owin;
        char x='X';
        char o='O';

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){

     xwin=0;
     owin=0;
     for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
      if(game[i][j]=='X'||game[i][j]=='T'){
        xwin++;
      }
      else if (game[i][j]=='O'||game[i][j]=='T'){
        owin++;
      }
       printf("row %d col %d x=%d o=%d\n",i,j,xwin,owin);
    }//close loop J//
     printf(" reset check  x=%d o=%d\n",xwin,owin);
     if(xwin==4||owin==4){
     break;
     }

   }//close loop i//

   if(xwin==4){// the return will be used later in call_func//
    return x;
   }
   else if(owin==4){
    return o;
   };
}//close row_check//


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int col_check(char game[][4])
{/*column check*/
    int xwin=0;
    int owin=0;
    char x='X';
    char o='O';

    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        xwin=0;
        owin=0;
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            if(game[i][j]=='X'||game[i][j]=='T')
                xwin++;
            else if (game[i][j]=='O'||game[i][j]=='T')
                owin++; 
            printf("col %d col %d x=%d o=%d\n",i,j,xwin,owin);
        }//close loop i//
        printf(" reset check  x=%d o=%d\n",xwin,owin);
         if(xwin==4||owin==4)
            break;
    }//close loop j//
    if(xwin==4){// the return will be used later in call_func//
        return x;
    }
    else if(owin==4){
        return o;
    };
}//close row_check//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int dia_check( char game[][4])
{//diagonal check//
    int xwin=0;
    int owin=0;
    int j=0;
    char x='X';
    char o='O';


    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){ //row increase by 1//

            if(game[i][j]=='X' || game[i][j]=='T')
            xwin++; 
            else if (game[i][j]=='O' || game[i][j]=='T')
            owin++;

            printf("dia %d check %d x=%d o=%d\n",i,j,xwin,owin);
            j++;
    }//close loops i// 
    if(xwin==4){// the return will be used later in call_func//
        printf("x\n");
        return x;
    }
    else if(owin==4){
        return o;
    };

}//close dia_check//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int dia2_check( char game[][4])
{//the other diagonal check//
    int xwin=0;
    int owin=0;
    int j=3;
    char x='X';
    char o='O';


    for(int i=0; i>0; i++){ //row increase by 1//

            if(game[i][j]=='X' || game[i][j]=='T'){
            xwin++;
            }
            else if (game[i][j]=='O' || game[i][j]=='T'){
            owin++;
            }
            printf("dia2 %d check %d x=%d o=%d\n",i,j,xwin,owin);
            j--;       
    }//close loops i// 
    if(xwin==4){// the return will be used later in call_func//
        return x;
    }
    else if(owin==4){
        return o;
    };
}//close dia2_check//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int draw_check(char game[][4])
{/*draw check */


    int draw=0;
    char d= '=';
    char p= '?'; // p for game in progress//
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            if(game[i][j]=='X'||game[i][j]=='T'||game[i][j]=='O'){
            draw++;

            }
             printf("draw %d col %d D %d\n",i,j,draw);
        } //close j for loop// 

       }//close i loop
   if(draw==16){//the return will be used later in call_func//
        return d;
        }
        else{
        return p; 
        }
}//close draw check//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 int call_func (char game[4][4])
 {//call functions //

    char x ;
    char o ;
    char d ;
    char p ;
   o,x=row_check(game);

   if(x=='X'){
        printf("X\n");
   }
   else if(o=='O'){
        printf("O\n");
   }
   else{//first else//
       x,o=col_check(game);
        if(x=='X'){
            printf("X");
        }
        else if(o=='O'){
            printf("O\n");
        }

        else{//second else//
            x,o=dia_check(game);
            if(x=='X'){
                printf("X");
            }
            else if(o=='O'){
                printf("O\n");
            }
           else{// third else//
                x,o=dia2_check(game);
                if(x=='X'){
                    printf("X");
                }
                else if(o=='O'){
                    printf("O\n");
                }
                else{//forth else//
                    p,d=draw_check(game);
                    if(d=='=')
                        printf("=\n");
                    else if(p=='?'&& x!='X' &&o!='O')
                        printf("?\n");
                }//close forth  else//
            }//close third else//
       }//close second else//
   }//close first else//  
}//close call_func//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{

    char game[4][4];


//input to test the array //   
    printf("inputs are x,o T or . \n");
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
         for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
           printf("game[%d][%d]\n",i,j);
           scanf(" %c",&game[i][j]);
         }
     };
  //output array//
    for (int g=0; g<4; g++){
      printf("\n");
      for(int h=0; h<4; h++){
        printf("%c",game[g][h]);
        }
     };
    printf("\n");


    printf("[OUTPUT]\n");
    call_func(game);  
}//close main//
```

i can not find out  where  is the problem.

Comment: can you explain how the output is generating in dia2 0 check 0 x=1 o=0

Comment: the fucnction chek if there x or t  it will add 1 to xwin  or if there is o  or t  will add 1 to owin 
if xwin ==4 the it will print x , same for owin 
dia2  is the function that chek the second diagonal staring from [0][3]
dia2 is the number of row, check is the number  column and  x the sum of xwin o is owin

Comment: dia2 0 check 0 x=1 o=0  mean 
in function dia2 row 0 colum 0 the ckeck is 1 x and 0 o

Comment: its really complicated... m trying

Comment: THIS is useless as the output is totally different than you posted when i checked

Comment: that output is very big more than 50 line but if you jump for part  dia 3 check 3 x=0 o=0 you will see the problem  there adter dia 3 ther should be dia2 0
what do you see ??

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistake in function dia2_check the loop is

```
for(int i=0; i>0; i++)
```

it should  be

```
for(int i=0; i>4; i++)
```

because  i always start from 0 than  the loop will be always jumped

now should i delete the post or no ??